# Get Ruby class constant dynamically by name

Tags: ruby, oop

I have a class API that pulls objects from a third party API and builds them into objects that are subclasses of type `APIObject`.  `APIObject` subclasses match the object names from the API that I'm pulling from:

```
User < APIObject
Account < APIObject
```

I would like to define a class method in APIObject that allows me to pull objects using standard Rails accessors:

```
user = User.find id
```

I would like the method to translate this call into an API call like this:

```
API::User::findById id
```

I would like to access the name of the APIObject subclass (`User`) using `self.class.name` and use that to call the constant (`API::User`), but I know `API::self.class.name` won't work.  I could rewrite this method over and over again for every subclass, but it seems like this should be possible without doing that.  Suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? So far all you've done is give us a list of requirements. That isn't what this site is for. We help you with code you're trying to write, we don't write it for you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think you’re looking for [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get). Perhaps something like:

```
def self.find(id)
  API.const_get(self.name).find_by_id(id)
end
```

(note you only need `self.name`, since this is already in the context of the class, and `self.class.name` will just be `Class`).

Comment: But if I define that method from within APIObject to be inherited by the child classes, I will need self.class.name.  Yes?  Sorry...still a bit of a newb to Rails.

Comment: @kid_drew No. If you want to call it like `User.find`, then it is a method on `User`, so `self` will already be the class you are interested in (i.e `User`). If you wanted to call it on instances of `User` (e.g. `a_user.find`) you would need `self.class`.

Comment: @kid_drew Note that in Ruby, when you inherit from a class, the class methods are inherited and are available on the subclass itself as well as instance methods being available on instances of the subclass.

Comment: const_get is awesome @matt